# How to get Windows 10 Chrome to accept the self signed certificate generated by CUPS admin on Linux

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, windows-10, self-signed

I have a ClearOs Linux server which, amongst other things, runs a CUPS print server. Installing CUPS makes an admin interface available via https protocol.

Every time I connect to this admin server, Chrome (and IE) warns me the certificate is invalid, and I have to click twice more to go through to the site.

I would like to tell Chrome to trust this certificate. I have Googled how to do this, and tried 3 or 4 different recipes - none of them seem to have worked (the certificate is still not trusted). I have tried the following:

Connect to the site via IE running as Administrator, click on the invalid certificate flash next to the url, view certificate, install certificate, choose Trusted Root Certificate store, and install it. I also tried the Personal store and the Trusted publishers store.

Connect to the site via Chrome, click on the certificate and export it, do Settings/Advanced/Manage certificates, and import it into the store (again, I tried Trusted Root and Personal stores).

I also tried some other instructions which said to start by running "MMC" from the Windows Start button - but typing MMC only offers me Hyper-V manager and Sql Server 2017 Configuration Manager - not the management console expected.

I have read [Getting Chrome to accept self-signed localhost certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate) here, and tried everything there that applies to Windows 10, but nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

Enter “**chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost**” in your chrome browser and “Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost.” to bypass the security warning about your self signed certificate.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work - presumably because the linux box is not localhost?

Comment: I don't know, I don't use Chrome that much